# Delete empty folders inside working directory

Tags: r

I have number of empty folders inside a working directory. Want to remove those empty folders in R. Can somebody help me out on this.

Comment: what sort of things have you tried? did you get stuck/get any specific errors? Is there a reason you can't just manually delete them?

Comment: I am doing this activity as part of automation. Weekly i need to schedule this activity. i have tried file.remove() and unlink() functions, but it is deleting only files inside the sub folders not the folder. Folder is remaining empty.

Comment: @Shriram you need `recursive = TRUE` in `unlink` to delete the folder.

Comment: Do you also need help identifying these folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the current directory is the one in which you want to delete the empty folders, you can do:

```
folders <- list.dirs(recursive = FALSE)
for(folder in folders){
  if(length(dir(folder)) == 0){
    unlink(folder, recursive = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can delete folders using:

```
unlink("path_to_non_empty_dir", recursive=TRUE)
```

## Edit: removed part about non-empty folders

From `?unlink`:

> If recursive = FALSE directories are not deleted, not even empty ones.

Comment: I have used `unlink("working directory path", recursive=TRUE)`  it is deleting files inside the folders but not able to delete folders.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? Because `unlink("deleteme", recursive = TRUE)` deletes the directory "deleteme" on my machine...